# Magento - How to remove color swatch if the product is disabled?

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches

For Example,There is a product with attribute color - Black,Blue,Red. If the associated product with color Black is disabled, it should not display black color swatch. 
But it displays color swatch(although disabled). How to remove it?
Using - Magento default ColorSwatches and theme rwd.

Answer (score 0):

Check in `System > configuration > inventory > Stock options > Display Out of Stock Products > No`

Comment: It is already set to No. but the scenario is that Product status is set to disabled. and it is still showing the disabled color swatch. but instead I need to remove that swatch.

Comment: Do reindex from admin index management

Comment: You can setup a cron to reindex every X minutes - then when a product runs OOS, it will automatically be removed from selection in time.